# Mapbox iOS: Updating Route while navigating

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am working with Mapbox to navigate users to some places. There are times when I need to update the route on the fly, for example when users should take a detour to a waypoint I set.

My Route Calculation works well. I create a navigationViewController and give it a routeResponse, a routeIndex, routeOptions and navigationOptions, then start the navigation with that.

```
navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: myRouteResponse, routeIndex: 0, routeOptions: myNavigationRouteOptions, navigationOptions: NavigationOptions())
navigationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
view.present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As stated, this works well and starts the navigation as it should.

Later on, when some event triggers, I calculate new Waypoints and a new route with waypoints. I then want to update the currently running NavigationViewController with the new route, which I am trying to do as can be seen in the following snippet:

```
let routeOptions = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: waypoints, profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)

    print("Calculating RouteResponse...")
    
    _ = Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions, completionHandler: { (waypoints, result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            guard let route = response.routes?.first else { return }
            self.newRoute = route
            
            print("""
            !!!
            Route Calculation Result:
            Found \(String(describing: response.routes?.count)) routes.
            !!!
            """)

            print("Updating Navigation...")
            self.navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: response, routeIndex: 0, routeOptions: self.myNavigationRouteOptions)  
           
            
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    })
```

Although this is not throwing any errors, it does not do what I expect either. I have sometimes managed to get two instances running, but never to replace the current one. How can that be done? I basically want to use the rerouting feature mapbox itself uses when users leave the recommended way, but with a completely new route. That shouldn't be all that hard, but I can't seem to get a response from the Mapbox team regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are re-assigning a presented view controller with a new object from the presenting view controller. This will not simply update the already presented view.

What you need is a method to update the routes inside the existing NavigationViewController instance. The router object (accessible through `navigationViewController.navigationService.router`) has an `updateRoute` method which accepts the new route response through a `IndexedRouteResponse` object.
I'm yet to test this method, but as per their docs this should work -> *Asynchronously replaces currently active route with the provided `IndexedRouteResponse`.*